# How do I show that the curve shares $y$ in exactly one point?

Tags: calculus

My function is 
$$(x-1)\sin(\pi y) = 4y-1 $$
And I did calculate the implicit derivation
$$y' = - \frac {\sin(\pi y)}{\pi x \cos(\pi y) - \pi \cos(\pi y)-4} $$

We also know that the curve goes through the point $ (1, \frac{1}{4}) $ and I calculated the tangent line as $y = 0.17x+0.08$ which might be wrong.

But how do I show that the curve is going through the $y$-axis at exactly one point.

Comment: You mentioned in a comment below that you are looking for the actual point that it crosses. The equation you have is what we call a transcendental equation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation), and as such cannot be solved analytically. You can only find a numerical approximation to the solution. Using Mathematica, I find it occurs at about $y=0.14208$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crossing the $y$-axis means a point of the form $(0,y)$ i.e. where $x=0$. If we apply this to your equation we have
$$
(x-1)\sin(\pi y)=4y-1\to \sin(\pi y)=1-4y
$$
We know sin is bounded between $-1$ and $1$ so from the R.H.S. we see that $0\leq y \leq \frac{1}{2}$. In this range, the L.H.S. is strictly increasing while the R.H.S. is strictly decreasing so it must be that they cross only once, or never. If you plug in $y=0$ you see that $\sin(\pi y)<1-4y$ but for $y=\frac{1}{2}$ we have $\sin(\pi y)>1-4y$ thus they must cross once somewhere in between.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the function intersects the $y$-axis when $x=0$ so we need to solve

$$-\sin (\pi y) = 4y-1$$

for $y$

We can [plot the two sides of this equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%3D+-sin(pi+y),+x%3D4y-1) to see that there is only one intersection [note the $y$ axis goes along and the $x$-axis goes up and down!].

I leave it to you to find the value for $y$ if you need it.

Comment: My problem is actually finding the y value, to be perfectly honest. Not sure how to take y out of the sin part

Comment: I was always told that a plot was sufficient to prove there was one intersection. Afraid I can't help you with solving the equations, but WolframAlpha gives the answer as [$\approx 0.14208$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+-sin(pi+y)%3D+4y-1) which might help a bit

Comment: You cannot solve this analytically, see my comment on your post.